# Clarifying RxJava Observable Threading with Retrofit

Tags: retrofit

At http://square.github.io/retrofit/ where it talks about asynchronous, there is a phrase "Observable requests are subscribed asynchronously and observed on the same thread that executed the HTTP request" where I wanted to clarify.

So in this case which thread that actually will execute the Http Request: Lets say main thread makes a call to Observable getUserPhoto(@Path("id") int id)? Will it be the main thread or thread that subscribe the request that execute the http request?

Answer (score 1):

Regarding to the documentation, it will be the thread which execute the request.

If the result of your request change something in the view, you may need to observe (consume) your result in the main thread. In this case, add a call to the observeOn method before you subscribe to your observable.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is yes, when you execute your method by using a service, using the observeOn method will create an "Observer" that will be waiting for an opportunity to execute the request once the mainThread has an opportunity to do so.

So first use .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()) to observe the main thread, and then subscribe the action or callback that will execute once you got a response from your remote API.

supposing you use this annotation in your API interface

```
@GET("/home")
Observable<Response> getHome();
```

this would be an example:

```
 service.getHome().observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()).subscribe(
               new Action1<Response>() {
                    @Override
                    public void call(Response response) {
                        System.out.println("Response home");
                        System.out.println(response.getStatus());
                        System.out.println(response.getBody().mimeType());
                        System.out.println(response.getReason());
                        System.out.println(response.getUrl());
                        StringWriter w = new StringWriter();
                        try{
                            IOUtils.copy(response.getBody().in(),w,"UTF-8");
                            System.out.println(w.toString());
                        }catch (IOException e){}

                    }
               });
```

For more information you may check this RxJava(the one that Retrofits uses of course) [link](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/The-RxJava-Android-Module) where it states that it uses Android's Handler(which is a class for handling threads)

"It provides a Scheduler that schedules an Observable on a given Android Handler thread, particularly the **main UI thread**."

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I understand on how we can specify main thread as the thread that is used when the response hits back to the observer. However from the phrase that I wanted to clarify, by default it says it would use the thread the execute HTTP request. I am still confused who actually execute the http request?

Comment: Your'e welcome, to clarify a little more perhaps it is more important to understand how Android handlers actually work. This you can find with a search in the Android documentation. Basically by default the handler adds a "task" into a Queue so when the main UI thread has a chance, this task would be executed, how ever it is possible to also create another thread since Runnables can be implemented using Android's Handler, also it uses an object called Looper which is a part of Android's thread management framework.